# Spring Boot Maven webapp folder and ResourceHandler

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

In my Maven project with Spring Boot I have a following folder with a static content(Html, CSS, JavaScript files):

```
/src/main/webapp/docs/
```

this is my application properties:

```
server.port: 8080
server.contextPath: /admin-api
```

When a user access a following url: `http://localhost:8080/admin-api/docs` I want to show him a static content from `/src/main/webapp/docs/` folder.

I'm trying to configure `ResourceHandler` in my `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` but it doesn't work:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        String[] staticResourceMappingPath = { "/docs/", "classpath:/docs/" };
        registry.addResourceHandler("/docs").addResourceLocations(staticResourceMappingPath);
    }

...
}
```

`http://localhost:8080/admin-api/docs` returns 404 Not Found.

What am I doing wrong and how to properly configure it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `addResourceHandlers` method should be like below.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
     registry.addResourceHandler("/docs/**").addResourceLocations("/docs/");
}
```

Now if you have a static page say `index.html` in docs folder then you can access it using http://localhost:8080/admin-api/docs/index.html